# Embed editable excel object in outlook mail

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, microsoft-outlook

I regularly send out a piece of an Excel spreadsheet for my coworkers to fill in, in an email. However, thus far I have only been able to do it as a normal (word kind) table, that doesn't support summation and value-based formatting.

How can I embed an excel spreadsheet in the email that is editable when my coworkers respond? All I have tried results in the embedded spreadsheet to be converted to an image as soon as they recieve it.

I do not want to link to the actual excel file on disk, since it requires a lot more input to work. I've had a look here http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/opening-an-embedded-excel-table-in-an-email/21565db4-2a3b-4435-8b7d-0a8ba42ec165, but it seems to only deal with the link method.

Office 365.

Comment: Why not just attach the .xls to your email?

Comment: Because then they'll have to open it, edit, save somewhere, reply to my message and attach the new file, instead of just editing in the email as-is. My goal is to make this as easy as possible, and that's just too many steps (meaning I wont get any responses).